# SciPy, differential equations wrong solution

Tags: python, math, scipy, physics

I create the program, which by  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3J7Z.png) formula, using matplotlib draws graph of the body flight path.
The code seems to be right, but i get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UZy3.png), x and y for some reasons is negative and from somewhere appears that line on top right.

I did SciPy code this by [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLtRK4Z1tEg&t=395s) video.

With first class everything is fine, so watch only to second class, which has to calculate this x and y coords.

What's wrong? Thanks.

```
from scipy import integrate
from math import sin, cos
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# constants:

g = 9.81

# input:

k = 0.05   # air resistance
angle = 60 # angle of throw
v0 = 5     # start velocity
m = 4      # mass of the body

class GraphTrajectoryAnimation:
    def __init__(self, x, y, color, m=1, lw=3, width=6, height=4, dpi=100):
        """
        Where x, y - NumPy lists with coordinates, color - color of line (default - choose by Random)
                        height, width, dpi - hw, dpi of the figure from PyLab.
        """
        self.figure = plt.figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi) # Init figure and his needs to plot 

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.m = m
        self.color = color
        self.lw = lw

    def animation(self, i, x, y, m, color):
        """ Definition of a matplotlib animation. """
        plt.plot(x[:i * self.m], y[:i * self.m], lw=self.lw, color=self.color)

    def graph(self, interval=1):
        """ Definition of cycle FuncAnimation, which call animation. """
        self.graph_id = animation.FuncAnimation(self.figure, self.animation,
                                            fargs=(self.x, self.y, self.m, self.color),
                                            repeat=False, interval=interval)

    def showfigure(self):
        """ Call the graph function and displays it on the figure. """
        self.graph()
        plt.show()

class SolveSystemOfADifferentialEquations:
    def __init__(self, k, angle, v0, m):

        self.k = k
        self.angle = angle
        self.m = m
        self.v0 = v0
        self.v0_x = self.v0 * cos(self.angle)
        self.v0_y = self.v0 * sin(self.angle)
        self.kdivm = self.k / self.m
        self.time = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

    def xmodel(self, X, t):
        x = X[0]
        dx = X[1]
        xdot = [ [], [] ]
        xdot[0] = dx
        xdot[1] = -self.kdivm * x
        return xdot

    def ymodel(self, Y, t):
        y = Y[0]
        dy = Y[1]
        ydot = [ [], [] ]
        ydot[0] = dy
        ydot[1] = -g - self.kdivm * dy
        return ydot

    def solveX(self):
        x = integrate.odeint(self.xmodel, [0, self.v0_x], self.time)
        return x

    def solveY(self):
        y = integrate.odeint(self.ymodel, [0, self.v0_y], self.time)
        return y

Solver = SolveSystemOfADifferentialEquations(k, angle, v0, m)
x = Solver.solveX()
y = Solver.solveY()

def show():
    root = GraphTrajectoryAnimation(x, y, 'blue')
    root.showfigure()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    show()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: In `ymodel`, calculation of `ydot[1]` should be `ydot[1] = -g - self.kdivm * y` (note the change on the right from `dy` to `y`).

Comment: i do that, but i also get this https://i.imgur.com/Iu2EtqB.png

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you're giving angles in degrees but sin and cos functions in python consider them as radians. So when you're writing sin(60), the program is considering sin(60 radians) instead of sin(60 degrees). Put π/3 radians instead of the 60 degrees as the initial angle of the projectile and it should work.

This should solve the problem of the negative value. However, I don't know why that other part of the plot is coming.